# CocosDenshion - I keep seeing exceptions thrown

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

We are using CocosDenshion for our games.
When we turn on exception breakpoints in xcode we keep getting exceptions from

status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(extRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(theOutputFormat), &theOutputFormat);

In CDOpenALSupport.m

(note that this exception does not crash the game as it is caught by CocosDenshion but still we want to see if we can prevent these exceptions).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the exception breakpoint to handle only Objective-C exceptions. This prevents these Cocosdenshion exceptions from being caught by the breakpoint.

I wager they're nothing to worry about, it's been like that for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Thanks! was worried that these cause performance problems or something